# simple numpy.sum raises ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy

I feel like I'm missing the obvious here, but when I try a really simple numpy.sum usage,

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(1,2)
```

I get the following error,

```
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

So I tried the following

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(1,2, axis = 0)
```

which gives the following error

```
TypeError: sum() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

Anyone have any words of wisdom? I feel like this should be as simple as it gets. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`help(np.sum)` shows the function's call signature:

```
In [72]: help(np.sum)
sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)
    Sum of array elements over a given axis.
```

When you call `np.sum(1, 2)`, `np.sum` receives two [positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-argument), 1 and 2.
 `a` is bound to the first positional argument, 1, and `axis` is bound to the second positional argument, 2.
This raises `ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds` because the array scalar, 
`np.array(1)` does not have a 2-axis.

When you call `np.sum(1, 2, axis=0)` then `a` is bound to 1, and `axis` is assigned twice, first by the positional argument 2, and also by the keyword argument `axis=0`. 
This causes Python to raise `TypeError: sum() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`.

When a function accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, the function signature is written this way:

```
func(x1 [, x2 [...]])
```

See for example, `zip`'s function signature:

```
In [84]: help(zip)
zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]
```

or simply ellipses are used:

```
In [83]: help(min)
min(...)
    min(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    min(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
```

As [juanchopanza shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31897146/190597), to pass both 1 and 2 to `a`, you could use

```
In [76]: np.sum([1,2])
Out[76]: 3
```

since `[1,2]` is *one object* -- the list containing 1 and 2.

Comment: Devils in the details. Thanks! Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) operates over an array-like object. So the following would work:

```
np.sum([1,2])
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
np.sum(a)
```

If in doubt, use the help:

```
>>> help(np.sum)
```